# Simple C++ vector usage

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

This is a part of my header file code so far:

```
class Class
{
   public:
        Class();
        void addSmallerClassToVector(int i1, int i2);
        vector<SmallerClass>* listofClasses;
};

void Class::addSmallerClassToVector(int i1, int i2)
{
        SmallerClass* sC = new SmallerClass(i1, i2);
        listofClasses.push_back(sC);
}
```

`SmallerClass` is just a simple class that holds two int values. However this code generates an error on the line `listofClasses.push_back(sC);`.

I also tried using `.insert()`, but there was the same problem. I tried using `->` instead of `.` and such, but the error says it has to do with `listofClasses` not having a type or something.

I want to add a class to the vector that already exists in the `Class` class. How do I do this?

Comment: "the error says it has to do with listofClasses not having a type or something."   In future it would probably be more sensible to quote the error verbatim rather than give us some sort of estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neet to set your vector to store pointers:

```
vector<SmallerClass*> listofClasses;
```

Or you can change your method to do:

```
SmallerClass sC(i1, i2);
listofClasses.push_back(sC);
```

What you did is declared a pointer to a vector holding SmallerClass.

```
vector<SmallerClass>* listOfClasses;
```

in your declaration is therefor not even initialized when you use it.
You can also do the following in your constructor then:

```
listOfClasses = new vector<SmallerClass>();
```

Then you have to use the `->` operator for the methods. But also note the other mentioned issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a very simple fix :)

Comment: The question was about a specific syntax problem and not about a discussion wether pointers are nice or not. Though I agree with mentioning and asking why pointers it is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Umm... well the number of data I have to store in this vector is fairly large. And I might need the SmallerClass to hold a separate vector class of its own. would it still be better not to use pointers?

Comment: Oh and also another small reason is that I learned coding in Java first so I feel more comfortable using pointers. Is this a bad habit in C++?

Comment: I suggest you open another question if you would like to discuss such a thing. programmers stackexchange may be a good resource for this

Comment: @user2058340 yes, it is generally a bad habit. You should only use them if you really know what you are doing. You have not given any valid reason for using them so far.

Comment: The syntax problem could have been solved in different ways. I think your way should at least include a health warning.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to fix is to change to:

```
vector<SmallerClass *> listofClasses;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, you can:

```
vector<SmallerClass> listofClasses;
...
SmallerClass sC(i1, i2);
listofClasses.push_back(sC);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a very simple fix :)

Comment: @user2058340 But it is probably a bad idea to store pointers. Do you have a strong reason to do so?

Comment: @juanchopanza It's not always a bad idea dependent on how you would use it.

Comment: True, but there is nothing in OP's code that suggests they need vectors of pointers. The fact that they store a pointer to a vector leads me to think they don't understand the implications...

Comment: Umm... well the number of data I have to store in this vector is fairly large. And I might need the SmallerClass to hold a separate vector class of its own. would it still be better not to use pointers?

Comment: @user2058340 I think it's OK to use pointers here. Of course, you need to know what they mean. You will need explicitly release them.

Comment: @user2058340 I tend to think pointers are a bad idea here too. You have to explicitly `delete` them and keep track of them thru exceptions. Your argument that _the number of data I have to store in this vector is very large_ does not hold a lot of water, because that data is stored somewhere in the heap anyway AND vectors normally are better for cache locality than a fragmented heap full of things...

Comment: Well I feel more comfortable using pointers because I started learning how to code in Java, which to my knowledge forces the use of pointers (according to my professor at least). However, if it's better to have vectors hold data directly, I'll make the change. Thank you all for you advices!

Answer (score 1):

The most robust solution would be to not store pointers in the vector. There is also no reason to store a pointer to a vector in `Class`.

```
#include <vector>

class Class
{
   public:
        Class();
        void addSmallerClassToVector(int i1, int i2);
        std::vector<SmallerClass> listofClasses;
};

void Class::addSmallerClassToVector(int i1, int i2)
{
        listofClasses.push_back(SmallerClass(i1, i2));
}
```